ReactJS can scroll in Chrome but can't in Safari
Weird thing happen to my React website. I've set style={maxHeight:...., overflow: 'auto'} to enable scrolling. It's working fine in Chrome but have an issue in Safari. After state changed, scroll is locked but I still can use mouse to scroll. Also, if I adjust browser size, scrolling will back to work again.
Please see example below. Sorry for the quality.
Example
I'm trying to make scrolling works in Safari. Any ReactJS expert please help!

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
